# Scraping data with BS4 - text strip() not working

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am looking to scrape some publicly available data from one of the technology/analyst research firms.

I have gotten so far that I can print out the title and position but the `text.strip()` function has not really worked - I am probably missing something obvious.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests.api import head

# get the data
data = requests.get("https://www.forrester.com/bio/michele-goetz?id=BIO5224")

# load data into bs4
soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text, "html.parser")

analyst_data = soup.find("div", { "class": "col-md-9" })
#print(analyst_data)
header_title = analyst_data.find("h1")
header_paragraph = analyst_data.find("p")
print(header_title,header_paragraph)

for data in header_title.find_all(), header_paragraph.find_all():
    name = data.find_all("h1")[0].text.strip()
    position = data.find_all("p")[1].text.strip()
    print(name , position)
```

Comment: is your for loop statement correct why are you using `find_all` method with out mentioning any tag name it will return list as empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already found a tag when doing:

```
header_title = analyst_data.find("h1")
header_paragraph = analyst_data.find("p")
```

therefore, there no point of creating this `for` loop:

```
for data in header_title.find_all(), header_paragraph.find_all():
    name = data.find_all("h1")[0].text.strip()
    position = data.find_all("p")[1].text.strip()
    print(name , position)
```

instead, call `.text` on `header_title` and `header_paragraph`. With your example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests.api import head

# get the data
data = requests.get("https://www.forrester.com/bio/michele-goetz?id=BIO5224")

# load data into bs4
soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text, "html.parser")

analyst_data = soup.find("div", { "class": "col-md-9" })
#print(analyst_data)
header_title = analyst_data.find("h1")
header_paragraph = analyst_data.find("p")
print(header_title.text.strip(), header_paragraph.text.strip())
```

Output:

```
Michele Goetz VP, Principal Analyst
```

Comment: Thank you, that really helps in clarifying  as to why I don't need the for loop.

Comment: Maybe as a follow-up if I want to get the text from the paragraphs below, would this be correct? 

analyst_data_bio = analyst_data_header.find("p")[2]
print(analyst_data_bio)

Comment: @CaptainAble2500 I'd narrow down the search to select those tags, they're under the class `px-0`. If you have difficulties, feel free to post a new question on Stack Overflow with showing what you have already tried.